# No transaction recorded in history with PayPal PHP SDK

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I have used PayPal PHP SDK following the code here:
http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/payments/CreatePaymentUsingPayPal.html

However, after a successful transaction, and redirection, there is no recorded history of this transaction. What might be the issue?

Comment: Please show your code, don't just link us to a reference implementation.  Also, which part of the code records the history of the transaction?  Maybe I missed it but I don't see any logging of the payment on the page you linked to.

Comment: @BeetleJuice does it means the payment code will not log the payment automatically? but there is other api calling that is needed? I am new to this and just code my payment feature following the example above